# Proving Relationship Between "Extreme Value Distributions" and "Order Statistics"

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I am interested in learning about the relationship between the two following concepts:

- Order Statistics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)
- Extreme Value Distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution)

In Probability and Statistics, the k-th Order Statistic describes the k-th smallest sample in a set of measurements. If we assume some underlying Probability Distribution for the sample, we can write the Marginal Probability Distribution of the r-th Order Statistic:

$$f(x)_r = \frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}F_x(x)\left[F_x(x)\right]^{r-1} \left[1 - F_x(x)\right]^{n-r}$$

On the other hand, Extreme Value Distributions are said to describe the probability distribution of the  maximum and the minimum points in a sample. As such, the Extreme Value Distributions are comprised of 3 types of Probability Distributions:

1. Gumbel Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution)
2. Frechet Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution)
3. Weibull Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution)

**My Question:** If I take the Probability Distribution of the Minimum Order Statistic or the Maximum Order Statistic - I think that these should be similar to the "Extreme Value Distributions" (after all, the "minimum" and "maximum" considered as "extremes"). **Thus, is there some mathematical proof that can be used to show that the Probability Distributions for the Minimum Order Statistic and the Maximum Order Statistic somehow converge to Extreme Value Distributions?**

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem

Comment: @  Qiaochu Yuan: Thank you for this reference!